# Why do we say some initialisms and acronyms as words but not others?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, acronyms, initialisms

Initialisms and acronyms with vowels can be said as single words. Is there any coherent pattern or convention determining the choice? VIP? LOL? DIY? WAG? For example?

Comment: I'd guess that 2 or 3 letter abbreviations are more likely to be pronounced as separate letters (SOS, VIP, etc), while with 4 or more letters, if it can be pronounced as a word (or even partly as a word, e.g. VTOL) then it will be. There's no hard and fast rule though, and you just have to learn it. (Some, e.g. LOL, can be pronounced in both ways.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much food for thought.